# Getting 500 error number on ftp

Tags: ftp

My ftp is connected successfully but then it gives 500 error. Have you guys had similar problem and do you know the solutions.

I tried to change password as well but it didn;t worked.

Comment: When exactly do you get the error? Show us your code. What FTP library/framework do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you getting error like 500 I won’t open a connection to xx.xx.xx.xx Ftp is showing as connected but directory listing is not coming.

The trouble is that your pasv command is telling the server to connect to the internal ip. Not your external ip.

You can find the answer here - http://tipsntrix.in/500-i-wont-open-a-connection-to-xx-xx-xx-xx/